# How to extract members of a group in Jenkins using Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I am using Active directory plugin and in a need of listing the members of a active directory group in Jenkins itself using groovy. I have tried below code and it always returns null.

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
String domain = 'my.domai.com'
String site = 'ldap.com:3268'
String server = 'ldap.com:3268'
String bindName = 'user'
String bindPassword = 'passwd'
adrealm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(domain, site, bindName, bindPassword, server)
adrealm.loadGroupByGroupname("my_team").getMembers()
```